# JOptionPane layout

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Okay, so I was wondering, how is it that this person has a different colour title bar, or border, along with a different icon for a JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE?

Then, we come to mine, I don't know if this is a layout thing, or what, but mine looks like this:

http://gyazo.com/afb7610cf65627fef07cab45485f7dfc // His

http://gyazo.com/5da7722a908169253559f5903509c2cd // Mine ( Can't post images, low rep )

How would I change mine, to the top one? I'd really appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is find out how to use Look and Feel of an application. That is how different systems have different looks, and also what separates yours from his. Here is a link to describe it to you :) [JOptionPane look and feel](http://ruby.fgcu.edu/courses/mpenderg/ism3230Notes/lookandfeel.html)

Another option you can do is check the javadoc(s) for the JOptionPane. It gives you many constructor defaults so that you have the ability to change the way it looks such as:

A list of options that you can do with JOptionPane that can be viewed [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/CreatingaJOptionPane.htm)

```
public JOptionPane()
JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane();

public JOptionPane(Object message)
JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("Message");

public JOptionPane(Object message, int messageType)
JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("Message",  JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

public JOptionPane(Object message, int messageType, int optionType)
JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("Question?",  JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

public JOptionPane(Object message, int messageType, int optionType,  Icon icon)
Icon printerIcon = new ImageIcon("yourFile.gif");
JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("Question?",  JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, printerIcon);

public JOptionPane(Object message, int messageType, int optionType, Icon icon,  Object options[ ])
Icon greenIcon = new DiamondIcon(Color.GREEN);
Icon redIcon = new DiamondIcon(Color.RED);
Object optionArray[] = new Object[] { greenIcon, redIcon} ;
JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("Question?",  JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, printerIcon,  optionArray);

public JOptionPane(Object message, int messageType, int optionType, Icon icon, Object options[], Object initialValue)
JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("Question?", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, printerIcon, optionArray, redIcon
```

hope this helps

Comment: yes. If you check the Javadoc(s) dealing with JOptionPane, and look in the constructors, you will see options dealing with many different icons, and different ways to make it your own :)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I've found out the Nimbus layout, I'm still trying to figure out how the title color works, all my buttons match his. Although, they have a blue outline, which I need to figure out how to remove. :D

Comment: the blue color around the button is most likely a Border issue. Check this webpage, and see if this helps..http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html

Comment: Okay, I've read and fixed that issue now, I've also found the; UIManager.put("nimbusBase", new Color(...));
UIManager.put("nimbusBlueGrey", new Color(...));
UIManager.put("control", new Color(...)); statements, but I still can't find how to change the titlebar via JOptionPane / JDialog, do I need to instance a JOptionPane object, or is there a set of syntax to do it?

Comment: Well, would you be able to upload the new image that you have for your JOptionPane? But when changing the color of the title bar, just 'import javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource;' and then type UIManager uim=new UIManager();  
uim.put("OptionPane.background",new ColorUIResource(255,0,0));  
uim.put("Panel.background",new ColorUIResource(255,0,0));   and test with those parameters, and see what you can come up with :)

Comment: I'm currently making the Layout on Photoshop, although, if you'd like, I could quickly code up JOptionPane, and some Dialogs, or I could show you the Layout :P